# Change the property of multiple buttons using classid in xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I want to change the BorderWidth property of multiple buttons using classid. Is it possible in xamarin forms. Something like *classid.BorderWidth = borderwidth*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xamarin Forms, to change the style of multiple controls of the same type, you have to use `Style` classes.

You can define a style at `Application` level or `page` level. Here is a style definition at page level:

```
<ContentPage ....>

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="myBigButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="10" />
        </Style>

    </ContentPage.Resources>
    . . .
```

To apply the style:

```
<Button x:Name="button1" Style="{StaticResource myBigButtonStyle}" ... />
```

But if you want to apply this style to ALL the buttons of your page, just remove the resource button style KEY:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="10" />
</Style>
```

then, do not apply any style to your buttons:

```
<Button x:Name="button1" ... />
```

All the `style` class documentation can be found here:
[Microsoft styles documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/index)

Syntax is not the same as html. But in the latest versions of Xamarin you can use CSS files to apply styles. But this option is still limited:
[Using CSS files with Xamarin Forms documentation](https://xamarinhelp.com/css-xamarin-forms/)